# Importing Python package

Tags: python, module, pip, python-import

I'm the owner of this [repo](https://github.com/FranGoitia/shapelets) and I'm trying to import it from another project. I installed it using pip via `pip install git+https://github.com/FranGoitia/shapelets`, but I'm not able to import it. I tried importing shapelets and shapelets_classifier and neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't install the git repo the right way.

try this:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/FranGoitia/shapelets@master#egg=shapelets_classifier-1.0-py3.5
```

then you can use 
    import shapelet

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the repository, the file you're actually trying to import from is shapelet.py, so try `import shapelet`